# MVC C# application, put content of file into string or List<string>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am uploading a file into a controller using the following -

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);

            //I want to put file contents into a string or List<string>

        }
    }
```

I would like to either put the contents of the file into a string then loop through the string which will be a delimited list,

*or*

loop through the incoming stream itself, creating a list of strings out of it.
I can't figure out how to do either. I assume I would use `file.InputStream` in some manner?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you know that your're file will be a text file why don't you use `System.IO.File.ReadAllText` ? Or maybe i'm not getting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `StreamReader`, something like this:

```
string s = (new StreamReader(file.InputStream)).ReadToEnd();
string[] ss = s.Split(","); // replace "," with your separator;
```